# Testing intel galileo examples with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2012, namespaces, intel-galileo

Trying to run some example code on Intel Galileo from http://ms-iot.github.io/content/16x2LCD.htm

Basically just writing characters to the LCD module.  The LiquidCrystal library does not work with Visual Studio because of compounding classes from different libraries.  Basically I am getting compile errors C2653, and some other errors because the class Print and the object print are used in different classes and compounded.  Anyone know of a way to fix the errors

```
    error C2011: 'Print' : 'class' type redefinition    
          class Print{
                  private:  int write_error;    
    error C2039: 'print' : is not a member of 'LiquidCrystal'
          lcd.print("Hello!");
    error C2504: 'Print' : base class undefined
          class LiquidCrystal : public Print {  public:
    error C2873: 'write' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration,
            using Print::write;
    error C2027: use of undefined type 'Print'
            using Print::write;
    error C2873: 'write' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 
            using Print::write;
```

I think the problem is due to the namespace not being recognized and the use of Print.h in the LCD class using Print for writing to the LCD display being overused.

How can I call the functions of Print in the LCD class so Print.h is not redefined every time it is called?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In addition to the errors, you may want to include some of the code that caused the errors to help people narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://sixfortyfour.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/displaying-intel-galileo-ip-address-on-a-16x2-lcd/
As a quick fix I modified Print.h and Stream.h, the files are located in {Galileo Project Folder}\packages\Microsoft.IoT.Galileo.Arduino.1.0.5\build\native\include. For Print.h I added:

```
#ifndef _PRINT_H
#define _PRINT_H

class Print
{
// Rest of print class
}

#endif
```

For Stream.h I changed:

`enter code here`class Stream : public Print -> class Stream

I checked the github repository and Print.h includes the changes, Stream.h still inherits from Print (https://github.com/ms-iot/galileo-sdk/tree/develop/source).

I also modified RS, ENABLE, D0, D1, D2, D3 to match the LCD configuration I used for a netduino project.